# [76.508][SEVERE]: Unable to receive message from renderer (in console)

Tags: selenium

Need answer for my query.

In my test script i am trying to accept alert and then table should get load after accepting alert but the same is not happening. I am getting a below error due to table is not getting loaded:-

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//table[contains(@id,'Content_gvSelectSeats')]/tbody"}
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)

Is this a sync issue??

Piece of code below:-

1) to click on fetch
    `reallocate.getReallocateclickFetch();` // simple click on button

2)now spinner will move and alert comes // waiting for alert and accepting it

```
 public boolean WaitUntilAlertLoad()
        {
             boolean foundAlert = false;
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30 /*timeout in seconds*/);
            do {


                for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
                {   

                    try {
                        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
                        foundAlert = true;
                        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        foundAlert = false;
                    }
                    if(i==99)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }while(foundAlert=false);
            return foundAlert;
        }
```

But still after accepting alert table is not getting loaded. What i should do??

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Before you switch to the `Alert` either to `Accept` or `Dismiss`, consider storing the windowHandle of the parent window in a String as follows:

```
//Stores the parent window handle
String windowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
```

Now, you can switch to the `Alert` either to `Accept` or `Dismiss` as follows:

```
//Perform your actions on the Alert by switching over
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Once you have completed with the actions with the Alert, consider switching back to the parent/main window through the windowHandle of the parent window stored in a String as follows:

```
//Switch back to the parent window
driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle );
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: No,it didnt help :(

Comment: Can you consider updating the Question with your recent code along with the changes and paste the error stack trace for further analysis? Thanks